# Make a linear model equation

Tags: linear-algebra

The starting salaries for teachers in Broward County for selected years are given in the table.

1995-27,910

2000-33,427

2005-37,000

2015-40,300

A) Assume starting salaries in the future increase at the same rate, use the years 1995 and 2015 to find a linear model (equation) that can be used to predict future starting salaries (let x=0 in year 1995).

B) In words, clearly explain the meaning of the variables in the model.

C) Write two questions related to this linear model. For one question give the information for the x-variable without saying x=? then answer the question and give a reasonable description then for the other question give the information for the y-variable without saying y=? and do the same thing

Comment: Welcome to MSE. We appreciate it if posters include some of their own attempts at the problem in their question.

Comment: It seems, that this exercise is about **linear regression**. Are you familiar with this method ?

Comment: no I am not familiar.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain all aspects of method of linear regression here. To start I just show you how to calculate the two coefficients of the regression line.

The equation of the regression line is $y_i=b_0+b_1\cdot x_i$

Let $Y=\left(\begin{array}{}  27,910 \\ 33,427 \\  37,000 \\  40,300\end{array} \right)$

and $X=\left(\begin{array}{} 1&0 \\ 1& 5 \\ 1&10 \\ 1&20 \end{array} \right)$

$b=\left(\begin{array}{} b_0 \\ b_1 \end{array} \right)$

You can calculate $b$ as follows:

$\textbf b=\left(\textbf{X´X}\right)^{-1}\cdot X^´\cdot \textbf Y $

$\textbf{X´}$ is the transposed matrix of $\textbf{X}$.

$\left(\textbf{X´X}\right)^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\textbf{X´X}$

This calculation can be done very well with Excel. If you have any question, feel free to ask.